# How many team project needed and which template to choose

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

We would like to use TFS2010

In my company, there is a single team working on multiple products at the same time. There is a visual studio solution for each product.
We can have the following scenarios:

Customer requirement 1 involves adding several features in product A  and must be deliver in May
Customer requirement 2 involves adding several features in product A & B and must be deliver in Aug
Customer requirement 3 involves adding several features in product A & C and must be deliver in Aug
Customer requirement 4 involves adding several features in product B  and must be deliver in Oct
Customer requirement 5 involves adding several features in product A & B and must be deliver in Oct

Developer Team is small (10 people) and can work on product a , b or c even though some developer know the product A  better than the product B and so on.

In reality, we have almost 10 products. Sometimes we have hot fixes and I have to track all activities.

What do you recommend ?  one or many team project ? if one team project, which structure do you recommend?   Agile or CMMI templlate ?

Answer (score 1):

The decision which project template to choose depends on you development process because the template represents it.

The CMMI template has a lot more fields for the workitem types (bug, task) than the agile one and is more formal. Take the time and think about your actual or future development process and take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400752) to get an overview.

The scenarios you are decribing are reached via a branching strategy, take a look at the [ALM Ranger branching guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/)

I would make one team project collection (because branching over team project collections is not possible).

I would create one team project and organize the products with the areas, iterations and team queries.

Reasons for my decicions

- each team project gets its the version control and sharepoint site
- you are a small team which work on all projects
- the administrative overhead for each team project

[Here](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/project-of-projects-with-team-foundation-server-2010/) you can find some good pictures and walkthroughs for working with one team project for different products.

Comment: I agree with this one TeamProject advise for an additional reason: As seen from the Release-aspect, the projects are tightly coupled. So, organizing a comprehensive reporting with any other choice can quickly become challenging.